# Validate original incoming value before cast to type on schematype mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I validate the type of incoming value before it is cast into the type that we specified in property type in Schematype?

I have a model schema like this (cut others properties like name, password  etc)

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    age : {
        type: Number, // type of data 
        default: 0, // if don't provided, client will has 0 for age value
        validate(value) { // 
            console.log(typeof(value));

            if(value === null){ 
                throw new Error("Age can not be empty string, really ?")
            } else if(value < 0) {
                throw new Error('Age must be a positive number')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Then I try to create a new user but I try to give boolean value into age, and it turns into value either 1 for true or 0 for false. I did some test, and what I got are:

1. value on validate function is the new value after it casted into type Number, so when it comes to validate() function, it can be 1 or 0
2. even if I put validate() function before type: Number. Still got the value is 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose will cast the model's values to the defined type in the schema whenever possible.

The casting is done when a model instance is created.

The validity of a model instance is checked just before saving it in the database.

Because the cast is done before the validity check, you are getting the value already cast in the `validate` function.

If you don't want the `Number SchemaType` to be cast when the value is not of type 
 number, there is a workaround defining a custom `set` method for the property. This `set` method receives the original value of the model as a parameter and it will be executed before the casting, so you have the chance to return a value that cannot be cast to a Number, for example a not empty string. This way, mongoose will throw a `ValidationError` when trying to save the model instance.

Like so:

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    age : {
        type: Number, // type of data 
        default: 0, // if don't provided, client will has 0 for age value
        set: v => typeof v !== 'number' ? 'Throw error' : v    
    }
});
```

For the Boolean SchemaType you can use the properties `convertToTrue` and `convertToFalse` to define which values should be cast to true or false respectively.

Please check [mongoose documention](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) for more information.

Comment: I have been using 'set' but didn't know if that recieve original type of incoming value, thank you !

Comment: @rochaf1 You are welcome! Please upvote and accept the answer so other users can find the solution if they face the same problem. See you around!